# Round Robin scheduling

Tags: scheduling, round-robin

I was trying to answer this questions If anyone can help please
A multiprogramming system uses the Round Robin scheduling policy with a quantum of 5 time units.

A process described below arrives at time 0:

CPU burst – 8 time units

I/O burst – 10 time units

CPU burst – 13 time units

I/O burst– 10 time units

CPU burst – 7 time units

Answer the following questions:

Describe the events in the process lifetime, and the state transitions it will undergo. For every type of state transition indicate whether it is voluntary or not, and justify your answer. Assume that the process completes its execution in the three CPU bursts presented. 
Cplt - Complete

this was my attempt

```
                                              Cplt            Cplt             Cplt  

|  P1 |  P2 |   P3  |   P4  |   P5   |  P1  |   P2  | P3   |   P4   | P5  |  P3  |

0     5      10      15      20       25      28      33     38      43     45    48
```

Events ; New -> Ready -> waiting -> runing -> Terminated

Comment: @user494310 - If that's homework, please tag it accordingly

Comment: Have taged it appropriately. however am confused wether its one Process reffered to or @ burst makes a process. if so then I can say am right.

Comment: I don't understand: what is P1, P2 ... ? Isn't just one process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give you my solution, but I don't know if I understand the problem at all.

1. CPU Burst 5q - unvoluntary transition - total 5
2. CPU Burst 3q - voluntary transtion - total 8
3. IDLE 10q (no other process) - total 18
4. CPU Burst 5q - unvoluntary transition - total 23
5. CPU Burst 5q - unvoluntary transition - total 28
6. CPU Burst 3q - voluntary transition - total 31
7. IDLE 10q (no other process) - total 41
8. CPU Burst 5q - unvoluntary transition - total 46
9. CPU Burst 3q - voluntary transition - total 49

Comment: Thanks, though I will try working out how the transitions are being made. Regardless of all THanks a lot, spent 5 days trying.